# "<br>" gets translated to actual tag, possible XSS?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-button

[image: XSS?]

the title of the question should be "why is <br> a tag..." but the literal html tag is being put in there. This is at least a bug, at worst arbitrary HTML being inserted into everyone's browser.

Comment: I've noticed this occurring in several StackApps as well... While most of SE is good about treating titles as plain text and encoding as-needed, it appears likely to become a stumbling block for new clients.

Comment: Just noticed this myself and came to note it :)

Comment: I hope someone doesn't ask : "Why is <script>alert('XSS')</script> so often used to test XSS ?"

Comment: @HoLyVieR they would have to both ask it and have it become popular

Comment: @HoLyVieR I actually considered that, but didn't think it would make it to "Hot questions".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A fix will be pushed out this evening - thanks for reporting this!