# Missing HTML escape

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications

> [image: Screenshot]
> <sub>(source: [adamhaskell.net](http://adamhaskell.net/img/sofail.png))</sub>

The actual title of the question is: <select> in Chrome has excessive padding?

Apparently, the "notifications" tab missed the HTML escape, resulting in this. Note that this could be abused to inject a `<script>` tag, then anyone who comments on it (such as to say "this is spam") would be at risk of injection.

Comment: I thought this was abused once before when they forgot to escape it somewhere else, I think they were just changing the entire page to a picture of a unicorn, though. Oh the fun times we have on Meta.

Comment: @animuson It was in the [hot questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61121/br-gets-translated-to-actual-tag-possible-xss) list. SE has a surprising number of [XSS bugs](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=xss)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed now. Only *migration* notifications weren't being properly escaped. Other types, such as badge grant notifications, were handled properly.

Useless trivia: this was the *second* (ever) post migrated from/to Stack Overflow with "`<select>`" in its title.

Comment: Interesting trivia. Have any had `<script>` in them?